# CoordinatorLayout. Scrolling stops when i try to scroll AppBarLayout area

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

There are CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout inside and CoordinatorLayoutInside appbar. There is RecyclerView below with ScrollingViewBehavior. All works correct, but I want to remove next effect:

When I swipe AppBar area from bottom to top scrolling stops when AppBar collapsed and for next scroll i must swipe RecyclerView. If i scroll RecyclerView there is no this effect.

AppBar height is 90% of screen height and in most cases user will scroll AppBar, not recycler. And this effect looks like bug. Anyone know how to remove this effect? Is this possible?

I tried to use any combinations of scroll flags, but it not helps. I think this effect happens because AppBarLayout "don't know" about views below it and scrolls self until collapsed. Looks like this page must be compound layout (scroll view with content) but it impossible in my case.

my layout at now looks like this https://gist.github.com/iamthevoid/48d2a57b586f942ca899a5416ee84439

Comment: Provide some code what you have tried.

Comment: Have you used kotlin- anko library?

Comment: @SumitShukla yep, it is anko

Comment: Sorry I can't help because I have never used it!!!!

Comment: @SumitShukla it is like xml layout but looks a bit different ))

Comment: Try this: lparams(matchParent, actionBarHeight) {
                            collapseMode = Parallax } and set flags to app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"

Comment: @SumitShukla these flags don't change the behavior. Unfortunately, I'm facing the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean fling effect? Can upload video to show that